# iAd in Xcode, connecting AdBannerView to delegate?

Tags: xcode, delegates, storyboard, iad

So, after watching Geeky Lemon's tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NkgmhpJovM&list=UU6-UA1FoMnbO2LCLWPCM9aA&index=27) on how to implement iAds into your app. My problem is, when I have all the code finished and try to connect my AdBannerView to the delegate, for some reason in the storyboard when I select the AdBannerView I can see the delegate connection in inspector on the right hand side, however there is no way to connect it. 
Here is my code.
My .h file:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,    ADBannerViewDelegate>         {
}
```

My .m file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"


@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController 

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

So in recap I need to know how to connect my banner to files owner, while using a storyboard?
Please can you help, any help given is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to connect your delegate is to select your Ad Banner View and then bring up the Outlet Collection inspector (on the right side).  Then control click on the "delegate" and drag the connection line over to your view controller, like this:

[image: One Way To Set A Delegate Connection]

Make sure you've set your view controller to be the right custom type, too!